# How to convert first worksheet of several excel workbooks into pdf in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

This is my first time working with PowerShell script. I want to convert first sheet of worksbooks to pdf. I got the code below which converts all worksheets of workbooks to pdf. How can I change this code to convert only first worksheet to pdf? Please help.

```
$path = "C:\Users\addns\Desktop\Template"

$xlFixedFormat = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.xlFixedFormatType" -as [type]

$excelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -include *.xls, *.xlsx -recurse

$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application

$objExcel.visible = $false

foreach($wb in $excelFiles)

{

 $filepath = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath ($wb.BaseName + ".pdf")

 $workbook = $objExcel.workbooks.open($wb.fullname, 1)

 $workbook.Saved = $true

"saving $filepath"

 $workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat($xlFixedFormat::xlTypePDF, $filepath)

 $objExcel.Workbooks.close()

}

$objExcel.Quit()
```

Comment: As an aside: you can simplify `"Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.xlFixedFormatType" -as [type]` to a type literal: `[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.xlFixedFormatType]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$workbook.WorkSheets.Item(1)` to get the first worksheet in `$workbook`, and then call your export function on that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I changed wb inside the for loop to $workbook.WorkSheets.Item(1)  and same on the export but it does not work.

Comment: can you replace this line `$workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat($xlFixedFormat::xlTypePDF, $filepath)` with `$workbook.WorkSheets.Item(1).ExportAsFixedFormat($xlFixedFormat::xlTypePDF, $filepath)`